# Counting the same column with different where conditions

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table called `employees`, whose schema looks like the following:

```
mysql> desc employees;
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| emp_no     | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| birth_date | date          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| first_name | varchar(14)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| last_name  | varchar(16)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| gender     | enum('M','F') | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| hire_date  | date          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I just want to query the count of `emp_no` for Males (`where generder = 'M')` and females (`where generder = 'F'`).

I want the results like:

```
+--------+--------+
| Male   | FeMale |
+--------+--------+
| 300    | 120    |
+--------+--------+
```

Any suggestion on how to do that in a single query?

Comment: Nope. The other article has the `Male` and `Female` in different rows not columns. Although I am sure this question is a duplicate of something on SO ^^ (Also the other question is for SQL Server which makes a duplicate even less likely...)

Comment: generder ? Wassat?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(gender = 'M') AS Male, SUM(gender = 'F') AS Female
FROM employees
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(case when gender = 'm' then 1 else 0 end) male,
sum(case when gender = 'f' then 1 else 0 end) female,
from employees
```

you could try something like that

Comment: You can save all the `case when` stuff since MySQL evaluates bools to 0 or 1